# C# How to read display templates location in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: development, 2013, master-page, display-template

Sharpeoint 2013 has a default filter template located at:

```
_catalogs/masterpage/Display%20Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js
```

How can I read the absolute path of the _catalogs masterpage in C# ?

Example of absolute path : `http://mymachine/_catalogs/masterpage/Display%20Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js`

so, if I'll load this file in a html script element, I will not get a 404 Not found error in the browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mymachine/_catalogs/masterpage/Display%20Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you not use the fact that `_catalogs` is a virtual directory in SharePoint and reference it like this:

```
<scrit type="text/javascript" src="/_catalogs/15/masterpage/Display%20Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js">
</script>
```

(notice the slash at first, and the 15 telling Sharepoint to look at the 15 hive instead of the 14 hive from 2010)

I also notice you have a typo in your "type" attribute (javscript instead of javascript)

Comment: Glad to help, please mark as the answer :)